# How to concatenate embeddings of completely different sizes (by rows and columns)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, tensor

I have embeddings of knowledge graphs by RDF2vec with dimensions `KG.shape=(7536, 500)` and embeddings of textual sentences by sentence bert with dimensions `text.shape=(14169, 384)`. I want to concatenate these embeddings of different dimensions.Although I tried making them equal dimension in columns by `z_text = numpy.zeros((14169,116), dtype=numpy.float32)` and append in text embeddings by `final_text=numpy.append(text, z_text, axis=1)` to make its dimensions (14169, 500) so as to match another KG dimensions (by column=500).

Is this approch okay or do we have better alternative? Does adding numpy.zeros will affect the performance of model while training? Could anyone help?

Comment: Why would you want to concatenate embeddings of different sizes? It has no meaning mathematically as you wouldn't be able to perform any truly useful transformations down the line. Of course, you could pad the shortest sequences to 500 just to make this happen but it would be a pretty worthless matrix for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @rudolfovic Thanks for your answer. Actually, my Knowledge graph embeddings generated by RDF2Vec with skipping some sentences where it does not find valid RDF triples URIs. But for the full dataset, which means actual sentences, I am using SBERT to generate embeddings for these sentences. So its dimensions are bigger than the Knowledge graphs embeddings. Then I am inserting the knowledge into actual sentences by concatenating their embeddings. Do you have any suggestions about this?

Comment: please state clearly what **exactly** each of the dimensions corresponds to in your arrays, what each array represents **exactly** and what you want your results to represent **exactly**

Comment: I have a dataset of shape (20242, 2) consisting of news titles and corresponding labels (1: fake news or 0: real news) which I train_test_split in dimensions (train: 14169,2)
(test: 6073,2). Now I generated the embeddings of text (news titles) of train data using SBERT, it came up with dimensions (14169, 384). And I have also generated the Knowledge graphs embeddings of same train data sentences which came up with dimensions  (7536, 500). So I want to concatenate these embeddings. So then want to feed the model with these final embeddings for classification(fake, real). Hope it is clear now?

Answer (score 0):

The technical way to do this is as such. You start with your two arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((7536, 500))
b = np.ones((14169,116))
```

Then you create your zeros:

```py
z = np.zeros((14169,384))
```

Then you append the zeros along the second dimension or `axis=1` (there can be only one dimension where the shapes do not align):

```py
bz = np.concatenate([b, z], axis=1)
```

Finally, you can combine one of your original arrays with the second padded array, this time along the first dimension (`axis=0`):

```py
c = np.concatenate([a, bz])
```

However, to reiterate my comment:

> Why would you want to concatenate embeddings of different sizes? It
> has no real meaning mathematically as you wouldn't be able to perform any
> truly useful transformations down the line. Of course, you could pad
> the shortest sequences to 500 just to make this happen but it would be
> a pretty worthless matrix for all intents and purposes.